# Joomla 3.9: Menu item set to Separator is not clickable to reveal sub-menu items

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu

I am building a website in Joomla, and I'm trying to make a menu in which some menu items should not have any article associated with it; clicking on them should only reveal the sub-menu items, but the rest of the page should stay static. So, I set that parent menu item to Separator, and added some sub-menu items to it. However, for some reason, the parent menu item is not clickable, meaning that I cannot reveal the sub-menu items.

Here is my website: http://vaterlinija.lt/

The parent menu item that has sub-menu items is the second one from the bottom (as you can see, it is non-clickable).

Here is a link to one of these sub-menu items to prove that they are in fact there, just for some reason not accessible through that parent menu item: http://vaterlinija.lt/index.php/saltiniai/1/mediena

How do I fix this? I tried using Menu Header and URL (set to #) instead, but the result is the same. The only way to make these sub-menu items to show is to set that parent menu item to something like Single Article or similar, which is precisely what I want to avoid. I am using my own template, made from scratch. Do I need to add something to CSS, maybe?

EDIT: I tried switching to the default Joomla templates, and the problem remains, so it's definitely not in my CSS.

Answer (score 0):

URL set to # is my preferred solution. What you're probably experiencing is menu caching. Try navigating to system > clear cache and clearing everything (or everything related to templates, menus).

There are some good extensions that add a clear cache button to the toolbar. They're ery helpful when setting up or rearranging navigation.